# How do I input/output .CSV data via a PHP page?

Tags: php, html, csv

I have the assignment below and I'm stuck at Step # 3 with the code file named *inputforassignment2.php* --basically, I am trying to append (add) rows to the existing data (songs.csv file) via that file with input fields. I tried to fix that code (which i obtained from a website, *see sample source code far below*, but it's returning errors or creates blank and numerical data in rows for each input.

Assignment: Create a simple PHP page that reads/writes to and from a .CSV file

1. The .CSV file should contain a list of your favorite items (for
   example: songs, games, books, authors, etc,..). Each record in your
   file should contain at least 3 attributes for your favorite item.
   Also, it should have at least 7 records. **--this part is done**
2. The PHP should read the file and display the records in a TABLE with
   the corresponding headers for each attribute of your favorite item.
   **--this part is done**
3. Also, in the page should be a link (**<< I did that part**) that takes to another page where a new record can be added to the file. Then the list should display all previous records plus the new one. (**<< where I am stuck**)

-all my current source files:

song.csv

```html
Song Title,Artist,Track Year
FLY,Sik-K,2017
Doverstreet,RIN,2017
Half Moon,Dean,2016
Blacklist,Loopy,2017
N/A,JooYoung,2018
Heyahe,ONE,2017
ADY,Sik-K,2017
```

assignment2.php [how this php code displays song.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgsZz.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Assignment 2</title>
</head>
<?php

echo "<table border=1> ";

$f = fopen("song.csv", "r"); //open a file in read mode

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) { //read the each line of csv file

echo "<tr>"; //for printing in the table

foreach ($line as $cell) { //each data of line

echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>"; //print in the table

}

echo "</tr> ";

}

fclose($f); //close file

echo " </table>";
 ?>
 <a href="assignment2/inputformassignment2.php">Click here to add more songs!</a>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

inputformassignment2.php

```html
<?php
//index.php

$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subject = '';


function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 if(empty($_POST["name"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
  }
 }
 
 if(empty($_POST["subject"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Subject is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $subject = clean_text($_POST["subject"]);
 }
 
 if($error == '')
 {
  $file_open = fopen("contact_data.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("contact_data.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
  $form_data = array(
   'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
   'name'  => $name,
   'email'  => $email,
   'subject' => $subject,

  );
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
  $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
  $name = '';
  $email = '';
  $subject = '';
 }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Add A New Song</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h2 align="center">Add A New Song</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
    <form method="post">
     <h3 align="center">Type below:</h3>
     <br />
     <?php echo $error; ?>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Song Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type your song title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Song Artist</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type the song artist here" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Track Year</label>
      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Put the song's track year here" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

sample source code obtained from website:

```html
<?php
//index.php

$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subject = '';
$message = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 if(empty($_POST["name"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
  }
 }
 if(empty($_POST["email"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $email = clean_text($_POST["email"]);
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
  }
 }
 if(empty($_POST["subject"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Subject is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $subject = clean_text($_POST["subject"]);
 }
 if(empty($_POST["message"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Message is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $message = clean_text($_POST["message"]);
 }

 if($error == '')
 {
  $file_open = fopen("contact_data.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("contact_data.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
  $form_data = array(
   'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
   'name'  => $name,
   'email'  => $email,
   'subject' => $subject,
   'message' => $message
  );
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
  $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
  $name = '';
  $email = '';
  $subject = '';
  $message = '';
 }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to Store Form data in CSV File using PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h2 align="center">How to Store Form data in CSV File using PHP</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
    <form method="post">
     <h3 align="center">Contact Form</h3>
     <br />
     <?php echo $error; ?>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Subject</label>
      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So step #3 is to create a PHP script that displays a form that when submitted, adds data to the CSV file, right? What have you tried so far? Is there any part in particular that you're stuck on?

Comment: lol @Phil yes I copied/paste the wrong thing

Comment: @phil, correct. I tried using this separate php page file with a sample form source code i got, to allow a user to input (append) rows to the original csv file, but i am stuck with issues such as inputs returning blank rows or rows with random numbers in them. And when i change the name of the variables, i am left with errors. Here's what I have so far:

-My modified code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16scjoffAG3bi4dIFaa-gtcPl-0QkH89l/view?usp=sharing
-Where i got the sample code: https://www.webslesson.info/2017/09/how-to-store-form-data-in-csv-file-using-php.html

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Phil, here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xYa2ydmW7-ftb-5AkLD3GPhvwTRWB-Ci

Comment: Again, please include all relevant code **in your question**. Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54662000/edit)

Comment: Ahh, apologies. I just did that. Thanks

Comment: No you haven't! Put the actual code in your question, not links to some other site. Again, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry again! I hope it all helps and makes sense now.

Comment: I don't see where you are opening the file for writing before you call your `fputcsv` line....  also, check your error logs they will likely tell you what is going on